# I can't select elements of an SVG I've loaded externally into D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to load an external SVG into D3 and then be able to select and manipulate using D3 functions. I was able to get it loaded on the page with the following code:

```
  d3.xml("external.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
    if (error) throw error;
    document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);                        
  })
```

However, when I try to use d3.select, none of the functions work. When I console.log the selected element, it shows an empty array.

Comment: You have to show more code than that. Even better, a [MCVE].

Comment: What is the console error? Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/1s2LJ3mMylqzYjveZlGl?p=preview) -taken from [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1014829), is your external.svg accessible? Is the path correct?

Comment: @mkaran here is a [fiddle link](http://plnkr.co/edit/GajRZ03qnuljoWpN8AQ4). It's not a console error, it's just showing an empty array

Comment: There are two types of javascript coders: ... and those who don't. Those who understand asynchronous code...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Best comment I read in a long time :P I wish I could award a bounty on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GajRZ03qnuljoWpN8AQ4?p=info) you provided, in order for your events to work properly, you need to add them after d3 has loaded the svg. 
So, instead of this:

```
d3.xml("DCMetroMap.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
    if (error) throw error;
    document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
  })

  // this runs before the above finishes, so d3 won't find something to select
  d3.select("#K05")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      console.log(d)
      console.log('hello')
    })

   console.log(d3.select("#K05"))
```

You need to move the select like this:

```
  d3.xml("DCMetroMap.svg").mimeType("image/svg+xml").get(function(error, xml) {
    if (error) throw error;
    // load the document 
    document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);

    //then add the events
    d3.select("#K05")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      console.log(d) // d will be null here
      console.log('hello')
      alert("Hi!")

    })

  })
```

Like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/WbYyBKtzZe6MtKGbjzw9?p=preview

In other words, anything you do, you must put it after `document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);`

Hope this helps! Good luck!